# Appinventor data triggered by GPS location

Tags: android, gps, smartphone, app-inventor

I want to create an app in appinventor which will be using gps coordinates to show some data. What I mean is that I want to make an app which will show a message whenever you go to an exact position. I already got the GPS coding that needs to be done but I'm not sure if I can save the data to somehow inside the gps. Im new at this so don't be too harsh with me! Is it even possible to do something like that in appinventor?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you're describing is a service, in which your program runs in the background waiting for the GPS to hit a trigger location.  App Inventor at his time does not have the capability to let you program a service.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your app manually and have it run in the background. As long as all permissions are enabled, it can then send push notifications using the appropriate block. I personally haven't experimented with what they display, but when properly done, it can show an image and text at the same time, one, or the other.

This means you could call the GPS when you reach a certain location, send a push notification with said text/image, which you can then view by the pulldown bar.
You could also have the app send yourself information via a text, replacing this with the push notification block, whenever you reach a certain latitude and longitude.